# how to send information at specific places in word file?

Tags: autohotkey

```
f1::
Gui, Add, Edit, x372 y-10 w0 h0 , Edit
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y10 w400 h30 , customer name
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y50 w400 h30 , customer's father name
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y90 w400 h30 , customer's address
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y130 w400 h30 , customer's mobile no
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y170 w400 h30 , loan amount
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y210 w400 h30 , loan date
Gui, Add, Edit, x22 y250 w400 h30 , repayment date
Gui, Add, Button, x42 y300 w130 h40 , submit
Gui, Add, Button, x242 y300 w130 h40 , cancel

Gui, Show, w479 h379, kcc
return

GuiClose:
buttonsubmit:
gui, submit

oWord := ComObjCreate("Word.Application")           
Document := oWord.Documents.Add                 
oWord.Selection.TypeText() 
oWord.Selection.TypeText()      
Document.SaveAs2("d:\mastercopy.pdf", 17)               
Document.Close(0)                       
oWord.Quit()

run, d:\mastercopy.pdf
ExitApp
```

friends i have made this script but this script is not working as i want. I want the information to be saved at specific places like-

Here i want that when i press submit button then this information like customer name, customer's father name, customer's address, customer's mobile no, loan amount, loan date, repayment date should get fixed at the specific places in a word file whose path is D:\mastercopy.docx and that word file should get saved as a pdf file at the same location with same name. now i tell you that where this information should get fixed at that word file. in fact there are unfilled templates of forms in mastercopy.docx and i want that this information should get fixed at requisite places as customer name should get fixed at page 1, line 6, character (with spaces) 43 and page 2, line 9, character (with spaces) 51. similarly customer's father name should get fixed at page 1, line 4, character (with spaces) 25. customer's address should get fixed at page 3, line 11, character (with spaces) 39. and so on..the other information will also get fixed at the specific places as i have told you above.. so friends please give me some idea how to make further part of the script to do this task.. i will be highly thankful to you...thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

It is very similar to a post you made a few weeks ago which was locked I think - it seems you only added a bit of code provided to you on one of the AutoHotkey forums. Why do you think you need to use AutoHotkey for this? Wouldn't bookmarks in the Word document be just as useful as you use these to quickly navigate ("jump") to specific locations? Or use Excel and insert values from Excel into your Word document. You should be able to find many tutorials explaining how to do this.

If you do want to use AutoHotkey: to start with, you have no variables associated with the Edit fields in your Gui, so how would you process the name for example? Your first step would be to be able to read the data entered in the Gui - you haven't gotten that far yet so fix that first.

Read about variables here http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#Edit